# Error when referencing a XML file to a XML schema(xsd)

Tags: xml, reference, xsd

**address.xml is as follows**

```
<!--address.xml-->
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE address SYSTEM "address.dtd">
<address 

    xmlns:personal="Personal things"
    xmlns:houses="Regarding to houses"  

    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsd:schemaLocation="address.xsd"

>
    <name>  
        <personal:title>Mr.</personal:title>
        <first-name>Samitha</first-name>
        <last-name>Chathuranga</last-name>
    </name>

    <house-id>
        <houses:title>107 B</houses:title>
        <NAME>Sam&apos;s Home</NAME>
        <!--  An intnal entity is used for the single quote in House Name here-->
    </house-id>
    <village>Poramba</village>
    <city district="Galle" province="Southern">AG</city>
    <postal-code>80300</postal-code>
    <country>Sri Lanka</country>
</address>
```

The errors when validated using java SAX parser are,

"Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "address".
Attribute "xmlns:xsd" must be declared for element type "address".
Attribute "xsd:schemaLocation" must be declared for element type "address"."

But if I removed the xsd referencing 3 lines, no errors come. Those lines are,

```
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsd:schemaLocation="address.xsd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems to address:

1. You are specifying both a DTD (via `DOCTYPE`) and an XML Schema (via
   `xsd:schemaLocation`).
2. You are specifying an XML declaration (`<?xml version ="1.0"
   encoding="UTF-8"?>`), but it is not on the first line of the file.
3. You are specifying a `schemaLocation` value that is not in terms of
   namespace-schema pairs.

Comment: 1)Can't we specify both DTD and an XML schema  for a single XML file??? 2)Adding comments to the first line of an XML file is OK  no? Eventhough there are any comments in the first lines the next first non-comment line is taken as the 1st line.

Comment: Your 3rd issue is not clear.. What are namespace-schema pairs? So how is the correct way?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE contacts SYSTEM "contacts.dtd">

<contacts xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="contacts.xsd" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <contact title="citizen"> 
    <firstname>Edwin</firstname> 
    <lastname>Dankert</lastname>
  </contact> 
</contacts>
Above code is taken from http://www.edankert.com/validate.html and there they have done the both referencings.

Comment: (1) Yes, if it wasn't a simple oversight, care will have to be taken that the DTD and XSDs are compatible. (2) No, not before the XML dec. (3) Read [How schema definitions are located on the Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#schema-loc)

Comment: do u mean we can't add comments before the xml declaration? That's quite strange.. I've seen many places where comments are added before xml declarations..

Comment: Right.  For well-formed XML documents, only one XML declaration is permitted, and it **must be at the top** if used.  See my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20251895/290085) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19898942/290085) for more details.