# Why can't I read this XML message via Java?

Tags: java, xml

I have the following XML, and I cannot access the tag `<description>`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck6mq.jpg

A simpler XML I can read well, but this I cannot.

Parsing code follows:

```
xmlFile = new File(route);
documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Comment: Can you just post the Xml as part of your question, photographed code is unpleasant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `comprobante` element contains another xml as text node. It is that nested xml which contains `description` element you are searching for. what you can do is:

```
doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
element = get comprobante element from doc
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(element.getTextContent());
doc = documentBuilder.parse(is);
now search for description element in this doc
```

Comment: EXCELLENT, I made a method to parse this part of code and I can now seamlessly access that data.
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `comprobante` element has an XML declaration in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

An XML declaration [may only appear once in an XML document and may only occur at the very top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251895/290085).  Anything else prevents the file from being [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) and will preclude use of conformant XML tools.  You must remove the extraneous XML declaration if you want to treat this data as XML.

Comment: xml get me that way, I can not change it, but I read it. :(