# XML Multiple Root Tags Error

Tags: xml

I have an xml file of this form.  It is not working due to a multiple root error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<message val="new" val2 = "1" val3 ="new"> Value </message>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? standalone="yes"?>
<message val="new" val2 = "1" val3 ="new"> Value </message>

    ...
```

Would there be any way to maintain this structure whilst fixing the xml?  Or more specifically: what would be the easiest way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you put the message nodes inside a root node like "messages" and then remove the extra xml declaration.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<messages>
   <message val="new" val2 = "1" val3 ="new"> Value </message>
   <message val="new" val2 = "1" val3 ="new"> Value </message>
</messages>
```

Having it with multiple declarations and no root node simply isn't well-formed XML and won't ever be able to be validated as a XML file or handled with any components that use XML.

Comment: **Suggestion**: Use ***well-formed*** rather than ***valid*** when referencing problems preventing data from being XML rather than problems preventing XML from adhering to an XSD.   See [**Well-formed vs Valid XML**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the reply. :)

Answer (score 1):

**No, there is no way whatsoever for an XML document to have multiple root elements.**  Furthermore, there is no way for an XML document to have multiple XML declarations as your example has.

The easiest way to fix your document would be to

1. Delete all XML declarations (`<?xml ... ?>`) other than the [first
   one at the very top of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251895/290085).
2. Wrap all other elements in a single root element.

If you don't make these corrections, your XML is not [well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) -- in fact, it's not even XML at all -- and you will not be able to use any XML libraries or tools to work with it.