# How to correct this : Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, decompiling

I am trying to open my project in Android Studio , but i get this error : *Content is not allowed in prolog*. My code is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myapp.mobile" platformBuildVersionCode="8" platformBuildVersionName="2.2">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
<activity android:label="myapp" android:name="com.myapp.mobile.Splash">
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.myapp.mobile.Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.mobile.ChooseMenu"/>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.mobile.LocalMenu"/>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.mobile.LocalMenuProducts"/>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.mobile.Cart"/>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.mobile.FinishOrder"/>
    <activity android:name="com.myapp.mobile.ReserveTable"/>
</application>
```

I had myapp.apk and decompiled using [Android Decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/)

Comment: You may have some characters before the `<`.

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna check all your XML files manifest + layouts (by copying them into Notepad++ or whatever) and see if there's any special characters like this one � and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have typo here (**myaspp**)

```
<activity android:label="myapp" android:name="com.myaspp.Splash">
```

and the intention was

```
 <activity android:label="myapp" android:name="com.myapp.Splash">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two XML declarations in your file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Delete one.   **There may only be at most one XML declaration in a file, and it can only appear at the very top.**

See also:  [Are multiple XML declarations in a document well-formed XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20251560/290085)