# Embedding XML (with XML declaration) in HTML or other XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, processing-instruction

I have the error :

> Error Parsing /WEB-INF/includes/VerDatosProyeccion.xhtml: Error
>   Traced[line: 4302] The processing instruction target matching
>   "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

I am using the code of same code of : http://jsfiddle.net/qxLn3h86/. I cut the code and past into my code.

My code looks like this :

```
        <table id="tbl1">


<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td>Amount</td>
    <td>Rebate (10%)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="1980-03-23">Mar 23 1980</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="1234.56">$ 1,234.56</td>
    <td data-formula="=RC[-1]/10" data-type="Number" data-style="Currency">$ 123.45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td data-type="DateTime" data-style="Date" data-value="1978-11-05">Nov 05 1978</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="2345.67">$ 2,345.67</td>
    <td data-formula="=RC[-1]/10" data-type="Number" data-style="Currency">$ 234.56</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tbl2">
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Available</td>
    <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bred</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value="1.89">$ 1.89</td>
    <td data-type="Boolean" data-value="1">yes</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-value="123">123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-style="Currency" data-value=".89">$ .89</td>
    <td data-type="Boolean" data-value="0">no</td>
    <td data-type="Number" data-value="0">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>


            <button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['Customers','Products'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>

</h:panelGroup>


<script>
    function exportarExcel(){
        $("#tableProyeccion").table2excel({
            exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
            name: "Worksheet Name",
            filename: "Proyeccion" //do not include extension
        });
    }
    </script>
<script>
    var tablesToExcel = (function() {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , tmplWorkbookXML ='<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
          + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
          + '<Styles>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
          + '</Styles>' 
          + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
        , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
        , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
          var ctx = "";
          var workbookXML = "";
          var worksheetsXML = "";
          var rowsXML = "";

          for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
            if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
            for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
              rowsXML += '<Row>'
              for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
                var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
                var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
                var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
                dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
                var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
                dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
                ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                       , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                       , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                       , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                      };
                rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
              }
              rowsXML += '</Row>'
            }
            ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
            worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
            rowsXML = "";
          }

          ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
          workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

    console.log(workbookXML);

          var link = document.createElement("A");
          link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
          link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
          link.target = '_blank';
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
      })();

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: The processing instruction target matching "\[xX\]\[mM\]\[lL\]" is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889132/error-the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### General answer

When XML declarations (`<?xml version="1.0" ?>`) appear anywhere other than at the very top of an XML document, parsers often confuse them with processing instructions and issue misleading error messages.

The ***canonical answer*** for fixing your error,

> Error
>   Traced[line: 4302] The processing instruction target matching
>   "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

and all similar errors related to XML declarations is covered by this Q/A:

- [Error: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889132/290085)

There you'll find solutions to the three causes of such errors:

1. Visible content before the XML declaration
2. Invisible content before the XML declaration
3. Duplicate XML declarations

---

**Suggestions for your particular case**

Trying wrapping your code within `script` with `CDATA`:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    ...code containing XML declaration (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`)
//]]>
</script>
```

so that the XML declaration isn't interpreted to be part of the enclosing document.  XML declarations can only appear at the very top of an XML document (and there can only be one of them at most).

If that doesn't resolve your problem, examine where you're outputting the XML declaration.  Make sure that there is no visible or invisible content ahead of the XML declaration, and make sure that there are not multiple XML declarations in the output.  For more details see:

- [Error: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889132/290085)
- [Are multiple XML declarations in a document well-formed XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20251560/290085)

Answer (score 16):

This can also happen if you have duplicate xml tag `<?xml version="1.0"...>` defined accidentally

Answer (score 6):

This error can also happen if you have **blank space before your xml** , happened to me in sending `xml` request with postman,

Removing blank space before request solved the issue.