# What is <?xml version="1.0"?>?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

What is the difference between

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

and

```
<xml version="1.0">
```

Why does it look like shorthand PHP in the XML tag? I'm sure that's what it is but why is it there?

I have an XML file that is throwing an error, but I couldn't find the error and now I'm assuming it's the `?` in the XML tag?

Comment: XML documents should begin with an XML declaration which specifies the version of XML being used. <?xml version="1.0"?> is OK. https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-documents

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### XML Declaration

`<?xml version="1.0"?>` is an [XML declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl).  It is an optional indication of the version of XML, the character encoding, and the standalone document declaration.  It can [only appear as the very top of an XML file, if anywhere, and may not be repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251560/are-multiple-xml-declarations-in-a-document-well-formed-xml).

`<xml version="1.0">` is an open tag (that will require a closing tag) to an XML element.  While it would be well-formed (if properly closed), do not use this -- it looks too much like an bungled XML declaration.  Moreover, the W3C XML Recommendation [states](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn):

> Names beginning with the string `"xml"`, or with any string which
> would match `(('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l'))`, are reserved for
> standardization in this or future versions of this specification.