# Does XML document have closing tag like HTML?

Tags: xml

In an HTML document there are HTML opening and closing tags: **`<html> </html>`** . Is this the same for XML?

For XML:
**`<?xml version="1.0"?>` 
does it need   `</xml>` ?**

I read here :https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp 
That the "The XML prolog does not have a closing tag". 
It seems confusing if and opening and closing tag are required for HTML ,but not XML. How does a machine know its at the end of the XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [XML declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) is not a tag. There is no end tag for it.

The XML document's root element will have a mandatory end tag. What tag that is will depend on the specific XML application (e.g. for [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(Web_standard)) it will be `<feed>...</feed>`).

(The HTML element's end tag is optional, as is its start tag).

Comment: This is the correct answer (+1).   See also [What is `<?xml version=“1.0”?>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45380229/290085)