# org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, sax

I have the following file that I `cURL`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <ProcessMessage xmlns="http://www.user.com/test/">
        <envelope>Encoded XML request message will go here</envelope>
      </ProcessMessage>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The full error I get is this:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
```

When I use the file with a `CDATA` element then everything works as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <ProcessMessage xmlns="http://www.user.com/test/">
         <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <envelope>Encoded XML request message will go here</envelope>
         ]]>
      </ProcessMessage>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any idea how I can accept an XML file without the `CDATA` part?

Answer (score 0):

quote: "Only one XML declaration is permitted in well-formed XML, and it must be at the top if anywhere."

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251895/3710053

So if you could get rid of that second `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` your okay.

Comment: The issue is not with the `<?xml ver...` part, it is with the first file where the `CDATA` is not part of the envelope.